# Django All-auth, disable automatic login with google

Tags: python, django, django-forms, google-oauth

I've got a similar problem to this question but I don't have enough reputation to comment on the original post.
[Django all-auth: How to disable automatic login via Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62831288/django-all-auth-how-to-disable-automatic-login-via-google)

I'd like the user to choose a specific google account (because I'm filtering by a company email), the automatic login doesn't allow the user to change accounts when signing up and instead brings them to the "sign up is closed" page.

Very new to Allauth and Oath so any help would be appreciated.

I'm overriding the defualtsocialaccountadapter to filter the emails getting through and that works fine on incognito.

Comment: I am also suffering from this problem.